# Why doesn't date appear in <p>?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

this is my HTML Code.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap_4.5.0\css\bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="bootstrap_stuff.js"></script>
<title>Home Page</title>

<!-- <style type="text/css">
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {

  background-color: #34495e;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;

  }
</style> -->
```

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <p id="demo" class="text-center">Date and Time</p>
    </div>
</html>
```

This is my .js File

```
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerText = d;
```

But i dont get a date in the paragraph? (I Tried innerHTML too)

Comment: If your script is in `<head>` the DOM isn't loaded yet. I assume that's what `bootstrap_stuff.js` is...

Comment: If the `<p>` is not part of the DOM yet, you're JavaScript code won't be able to find it. You're probably getting an error from the browser; check the developer console. The solution is to move the `<script>` tag to the end of the body, or put the code in a "load" or "ready" handler.

Comment: i tested it on my own, it worked, maybe your js didnt executed. have you try to test it like `document.getElementById("demo").innerText = 'Try';`

Comment: @Pointy Yeah Pal, it worked. Man this stuff is nerve wrecking !

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping this in a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var d = new Date(); 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerText = d;
});
```

This script should only run after all the HTML elements have been loaded

Answer (score 1):

you need to call your function on load event because the elements you're trying to access is not there at the time your function execute. when you wrap it in a event then browser will call it once HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed.

This code will work for you:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var d = new Date(); 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerText = d;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Kind Hearts of Overflow (Damn fast as well). I just moved my 'Script' tag to the end of the 'Body' tag and it worked.